# Is having something on used only for clothes?

Tags: phrase-request

I said to somebody that I have braces on. I meant to say that I wear braces. Would what I said sound odd to a native English speaker? If yes, then how else could I have said it?

Comment: Do you mean tooth braces or things to hold your trousers up?

Comment: @KateBunting, I mean tooth braces.

Comment: OK, so they are _on_ your teeth but _in_ your mouth. You could have said that you have your braces in. I would say 'I have my glasses on' but 'I have my contact lenses in'.

Comment: You'd only say you have braces on if you could easily take them off. Because that's impossible, you'd say "I'm wearing braces".

Answer (score 2):

Generally, **having something on** applies to something that you can easily **put on** and **take off**.  This applies not just to clothing, but also to things like makeup or sunscreen.

For something more permanent, like a tattoo, you would just say that you **have a tattoo** without adding the word "on", because you can't easily **put on** or **take off** a tattoo.  Braces are like a tattoo - you can't put them on or take them on yourself, you need an extended professional process to do it, so you would just say, **"I have braces."**

Finally, for permanent things, you can use **having something on a body part**. So you can **have a tattoo on your ankle** or **have a birthmark on your face** or **have braces on your teeth**. This construction also works for temporary things - you can **have a hat on your head** or just **have a hat on**.